# ReactJS and rendering issue

Tags: css, reactjs

I was just creating a web app using ReactJS but the problem is, the background image is not getting rendered properly.

Given below is the code snippet.

```
class WeatherComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            key: 'XXXXXXXXX',
            place: 'New York',
            temperature: '17',
            description: 'Light Rain'  
        }
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.update=this.update.bind(this);
    }
    update(values){
        this.setState({ temperature: values.current.temperature })
        this.setState({ description: values.current.weather_descriptions[0] })
    }

    handleSubmit(value){
        fetch('http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=' + this.state.key  +'&query='+ value.place)
            .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(values=>this.update(values))
        this.setState({ place: value.place })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className='background-style'>
                <div className='box'>
                    <div className='search-box'>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="search"/>
                        <button type='submit' className='button text-small'>Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
}
```

The CSS file is:

```
.text{
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow';
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: crimson;
}
.text-small{
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: white;
}
.box{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  width: 450px;
  height: 700px;
  background-image: url("./assets/images/wall.jpg");

}
.search-box{
  position: absolute;

}
.button {
  background-color: rebeccapurple; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.background-style{
  background-image: url("./assets/images/sunny.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

- If I change the `.box.position` attribute to `relative` in the CSS file, the background image is rendered but then the search box is not rendered. Making the attribute `absolute` completely removes the background image from rendering, I don't know why this happens, some help to solve this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: It rendered fine to me. I just cut and paste your code. Check this out -> https://codesandbox.io/s/test-s3w7t

Comment: Yes, but are you using the CSS classes?

Comment: yeh still fine https://codesandbox.io/s/test-s3w7t?file=/index.css

Comment: yeah, well I'll restart the server and check it out

Comment: I edited the question to address the new issue.